# How to specify liquid layout with swfobject?

Tags: flash, swfobject

```
swfobject.embedSWF("flash/main.swf", "myContent", "100%", "100%"...
```

It turns out the above doesn't work,how can I instruct to swfobject that I want the swf to be as wide/high as possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it takes more than setting 100% in SWFObject... you have to adjust your page's HTML and CSS accordingly.

see http://learnswfobject.com/advanced-topics/100-width-and-height-in-browser/ for instructions and examples